# How do you implement a mongo aggregate pipeline within the pre middleware?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas - Products & Orders - the each order contains an array of products referenced by the object.id. What I'm trying to do is $sum over the product.sellPrice in the array and set totalSale before saving the new order document.

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 products: [
 {
   type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   ref: "Product"
 }
],
totalSale: {
  type: Number,
  min: 0
}
});


 const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: {
          type: String,
          unique: true,
          required: true
   },
   sellPrice: {
          type: Number,
          min: 0,
          required: true
   }}):
```

So each order would contain an array of products. So what tried doing was in the orderSchema.pre('save') hook, I tried running an aggregation like so:

```
orderSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  let order = this;
  order.totalSale = order.aggregate([
     { $unwind: { path: "$products" } },
     { $group: { _id: null, $sum: {} } }
  ]);
```

Is this even possible or is there a better way to sum up the prices of each product for the order. It doesnt really have to be pre('save')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, yes, it is possible to use aggregate function in pre.

If you want to use it, you need to add `$lookup` in your aggregation pipeline to populate product data into the order.

How about just using `find()` on Product?

```
const Product = mongoose.model('Product');

OrderSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    let order = this;

    // if products array is empty, skip the process
    if (!this.products || !Array.isArray(this.products) || !this.products.length < 1) {
        return next();
    }

    Product.find({ $in: this.products }, { sellPrice: 1 })
        .lean()
        .exec(function (err, products) {
            let totalSale = 0;

            if (Array.isArray(products)) {
                products.forEach(product => {
                    totalSale += product.sellPrice;
                });
            }

            order.totalSale = totalSale;
            next(err);
        });
});
```

Comment: Interestingly this is similar to what I was just trying, however i tried using findOne. I tried what you just suggested and throws an `undefined` error on the products array. I think its to do with how you the find(). does it need an id?

Comment: @AnirvanAwatramani I think you should use find(), instead of using findOne(). Because you have multiple product on a single order, if you want to calculate total sale price, then you need to run multiple findOne(), which is not efficient. I edited my code, please have a look.

Comment: You're update makes sense. The function crashes without adding an _id to find(). However, the problem is creeping up with the return value from the find() function. It is returning an array of just the first item from order.products.

Answer (score 0):

```
orderSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
  let order = this;
  let temp = order.products.map(product => {
    return { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(product) };
  });
  let totalSale = 0;
  let promises = Product.find({ _id: { $in: temp } }).exec();
  promises
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(product => {
        totalSale += product.sellPrice;
      });
      order.totalSale = totalSale;
      next();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

Since find returns all matching the conditions, I saved them in a variable and then iterated over them.